# How to pass NSDateComponent as a function parameter

Tags: swift, function, parameter-passing

How do I pass an NSDateComponent object or reference as a function parameter (read-only)?  The following code fails at "compile" time with a " Use of undeclared type 'NSDateComponent'" error:

```
import Foundation
class PreventativeCare {
    var birthday = NSDateComponents()
    func setPatientDOB(birthdate:NSDateComponent /* compile error */ ) {
        birthday.day = birthdate.day
        birthday.month = birthdate.month
        birthday.year = birthdate.year
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've just missed the `s` in `NSDateComponents` :) Easy mistake to make, particularly because plural types in Cocoa are on the rare side.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected NSDateComponent to NSDateComponents and it works well.

Comment: Note that you should be using the Swift object, `DateComponents`, not the Objective-C version, `NSDateComponents`